# Import N relation types from CSV matrix to Neo4j

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher, relation

I want to import relations from a CSV into Neo4j with `LOAD CSV`. 
The CSV looks like:

```
id, name, element1, element2,..., elementX
1, element1,,1;2,2;5,,1;2,...
2, element2,3,,4;5,...
...
```

There are X elements with N relation types to each other. How do I iterate through the elementX lines?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS line WITH line
WHERE line.element1 IS NOT NULL
Match (c:element{id: toInteger(line.id),name: line.name}) 
Match (d:element{name:'element1'})
Merge (d)-[:REL{type: line.element1}]-(c)
return c,d
```

By using this cypher command, I can only add the relations for one elementX line, how do I iterate through each of the X element lines? And how do I cope with the semicolons ; between the relation types in order to have separate relations if necessary?

Comment: 1. If there are `X` elements, does your CSV file contain exactly `X` lines (besides the header line)? 2. Do you really not care about the directionality of the `REL` relationships created by the `MERGE` clause? 3. Do you ever want a `REL` relationship from a node back to itself?

Comment: 1. The CSV file contains exactly X lines + 2 header lines. 2. Currently its meant to be bidirectional, with the outlook to care about directions. 3. There will never be a self  referring relationship.

Comment: 1. `LOAD CSV` only supports a single header line. Your example also does not show a second header line. Are you sure you have 2? 3. OK. Your existing Cypher code can create a "self referring relationship", which is why I asked.

Comment: 1. Only the one header line I mentioned is needed, so you are right its only one header line! 3. There are no `REL` to a node back to itself in the input CSV. I am still struggling with on how to iterate through all rows respectively columns, is there any way in cypher?Thanks